# woocommerce-not getting confirmation mail after an order placed

Tags: php, woocommerce

Installed an E commerce website in both Linux and Windows server.i am getting confirmation mail from Linux Server after an order placed but not getting confirmation mail from Windows Server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

change in woocommerce.php

if u search function mailer() changed following lines:

```
include_once( 'classes/emails/class-wc-emails.php' )
```

to

```
include_once( 'classes/class-wc-email.php' );

$this->woocommerce_email = new WC_Emails();
```

to

```
$this->woocommerce_email = new WC_Email();
```

i think this will solve the problem...

just search if **classes/emails/class-wc-emails.php** in woocommerce plugin exists then u don't need to change..